# jQuery Drag and Drop issue - div id and class dependent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two draggable images, 1 man and 1 woman. When I drag the man into one of two divs I want to hide the image that is there and show a new specific image. When I drag the woman into that same div I want to hide the existing image and to show a separate different image.

There are two separate divs of the above example. Two draggable images into two separate divs. The incoming image will determine what hides and what shows.  I have my code so far below. It's not working.  I know the && is out of place.

```
    $('#drag-woman').draggable({helper:'clone'});
$('#drag-man').draggable({helper:'clone'});  // makes top images draggable

$("#drop-area-contain").droppable({  //makes contents in div droppable
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    if((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-woman') && (class == "quid-contain"){  //if id is dragged do this

       $('.quid-empty').hide();
       $('.quid-with-woman').show();

    }else if((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-woman') && (class == "hostile-contain"){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.hostile-empty').hide();
       $('.hostile-with-woman').show();

    }else if((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-man') && (class == "quid-contain"){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.quid-empty').hide();
       $('.quid-with-man').show();

    }else if((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-man') && (class == "hostile-contain"){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.hostile-empty').hide();
       $('.hostile-with-man').show();

    }
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mcmattgr/ocr0zh4t/2/)

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Added JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the syntax errors in the JSFiddle.

```
$('#drag-woman').draggable({helper:'clone'});
$('#drag-man').draggable({helper:'clone'});  // makes top images draggable

$("#drop-area-contain").droppable({  //makes contents in div droppable
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    if(((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-woman') && ($(this).hasClass("quid-contain"))){  //if id is dragged do this

       $('.quid-empty').hide();
       $('.quid-with-woman').show();

    }else if(((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-woman') && ($(this).hasClass("hostile-contain"))){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.hostile-empty').hide();
       $('.hostile-with-woman').show();

    }else if(((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-man') && ($(this).hasClass("quid-contain"))){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.quid-empty').hide();
       $('.quid-with-man').show();

    }else if(((ui.draggable.attr("id")) == 'drag-man') && ($(this).hasClass("hostile-contain"))){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.hostile-empty').hide();
       $('.hostile-with-man').show();

    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svz0bax5/

EDIT

I have added a closing to the parantheses for the conditions at the `if` and `else if` parts. Also, instead of comparing a nonexistent `class` variable `.hasClass()` is being called.

EDIT2

Simplified if-else:

```
$('#drag-woman').draggable({helper:'clone'});
$('#drag-man').draggable({helper:'clone'});  // makes top images draggable

$("#drop-area-contain").droppable({  //makes contents in div droppable
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    var idArray = ["drag-woman", "drag-man"];
    if((idArray.indexOf(ui.draggable.attr("id")) + 1) && $(this).hasClass("quid-contain")) {  //if id is dragged do this

       $('.quid-empty').hide();
       $('.quid-with-' + this.id.substring(5)).show();

    }else if ((idArray.indexOf(ui.draggable.attr("id")) + 1) && $(this).hasClass("hostile-contain")){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.hostile-empty').hide();
       $('.hostile-with-' + this.id.substring(5)).show();
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT3

In the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1btx6rfp/

We can see the solution:

```
$('#drag-woman').draggable({helper:'clone'});
$('#drag-man').draggable({helper:'clone'});  // makes top images draggable

$(".quid-contain, .hostile-contain").droppable({  //makes contents in div droppable
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    var idArray = ["drag-woman", "drag-man"];$('#drag-woman').draggable({helper:'clone'});
$('#drag-man').draggable({helper:'clone'});  // makes top images draggable
    if((idArray.indexOf(ui.draggable.attr("id")) + 1) && $(this).hasClass("quid-contain")) {  //if id is dragged do this

       $('.quid-with-' + ui.draggable.attr("id").substring(5)).show().siblings().hide();

    }else if ((idArray.indexOf(ui.draggable.attr("id")) + 1) && $(this).hasClass("hostile-contain")){  // else if dragged do this

       $('.hostile-with-' + ui.draggable.attr("id").substring(5)).show().siblings().hide();
    }
  }
});
```

We have a simplified if and the drop event is handled correctly.

Comment: @TylerRoper thank you for the constructive criticism, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for that. The "drag-man" and "drag-woman" ids are images in a div that are meant to be dragged into a separate div and execute the show/hides that are indicative of the hasClass container.  Should they not be paired together in the same part of the if statement?

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan you are welcome. Unfortunately I am not in context of your question. You could upload some sample images somewhere online and use them in the code so we will have a visual clue. We have never seen the man and woman and I personally do not understand the exact goal you intend to achieve at this point.

Comment: I'm creating an educational one-pager. I have two people(draggable images) that are to be dragged (jQuery) into two possible scenarios. Two scenarios for the man and two for the woman. When the image is dropped into one of the droppable divs the image that was there hides and an outcome image shows. I know I'm almost there.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan now I understand your question from the previous comment. You can group these into a single if for quid and a single else for hostile.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Does that eliminate the need for the secondary operator on the if statement?

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan I have edited my answer, simplified the if. I did not test the simplified code though.

Comment: I don't feel that the if statements are correct. The drag-man and drag-woman ids won't have the classes of quid or hostile contain. The "contain" classes are the different divs that they would be dragged and dropped to.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan I have edited my answer. This was my last reaction to your comments before you either accept my answer or make sure that your pictures appear at JSFiddle. Since there are no pictures, it is impossible to test it sensibly.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan thank you, this largely simplified the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you, Thank You, Thank You. What is your Twitter handle? I like your work.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan you are welcome, I do not use Twitter and am not very active on the social media, unless I'm testing some feature.